# Get my base class to increment my derived class objects integer

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the following code, how would I get the function the base class function clocks::increment() to increment the derived class object thing2.hrs without modifying main()? If I add temporary cout statements in increment(), the call "thing2.increment()" seems to be incrementing a base class object's member or a random memory spot if I haven't created a base object.  Without modifying the call in main() to pass a variable (and modifying the function), is the only solution to override the function with a new definition in the derived class?

```
   class clocks
{
public:
    clocks();
    void increment();

private:
    int hrs;
};
clocks::clocks()
{
    hrs = 1;
}
void clocks::increment()
{
    hrs++;
}



class childClock : public clocks
{
public:
    childClock();
    int hrs;
};
childClock::childClock()
{
    hrs = 2;
}


int main()
{
    clocks thing;
    childClock thing2;

    cout << thing2.hrs<<" ";
    thing2.increment();
    cout << thing2.hrs;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'have't created base object'?

Comment: You're shadowing the `hrs` member in the derived class. Did you mean to make it `protected` instead? To access the base member, you *could* use `thing2.clocks::hrs` if it wasn't private.

Comment: `childClock` has two `hrs` members. Is that the intent?

Comment: The answer below cleared up my misunderstanding, but SergeyA - I meant that if I ran the program with the first line in main (clocks thing) commented out that the program still ran, but even weirder. Bartek - This was a small part of an assignment and the class was defined for me as well as main(), and I was not to modify them. Alter and Rivasa(below in the answer) cleared up my misunderstanding. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things.

1. You don't need a second `hrs` in the child class, as the base class has already declared this member.
2. `hrs` should be protected, so the child class can access/set it, and you can use a getter to access the value instead.

Following these notes, we can edit your code a bit as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class clocks{
public:
    clocks();
    void increment();
    int getHrs();
protected:
    int hrs;
};

clocks::clocks(){
    hrs = 1;
}

int clocks::getHrs(){
  return hrs;
}

void clocks::increment(){
    hrs++;
}

class childClock : public clocks{
  public:
  childClock();
};

childClock::childClock(){
  hrs = 2;
}

int main(){
    clocks thing;
    childClock thing2;
    std::cout << thing2.getHrs() <<" ";
    thing2.increment();
    std::cout << thing2.getHrs();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, much thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding - I mistakenly thought that if the base class declaration was private that the member wouldn't exist in derived classes at all.